# ssl for facebook https is not working

Tags: facebook, ssl, ubuntu, https

From the website, i am writing an iframe which is showing on a facebook page, the problem is users navigating with https:// are getting a certificate error.

So i created a self signed certificate, but it failed because its not trusted.

Now i want to buy a certificate in order to stop the error from showing but i dont have any idea on what to get, and what is the difference between the options that are listed.

https://secure.servergrove.com/clients/cart.php?gid=23

Am looking to buy between one of those, if any one can help me with the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a similar certificate installed on my site.

Based on that, and how it's working with FB now, I'd recommend that you get the QuickSSL® certificate.

Unless you're setting up a full fledged e-commerce site, including mobile, the QuickSSL® should work for a standard iFrame app on FB.